# Display array (converted from string) on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code snippet which is meant to return an array on click of 'button', the string converted to an array comes from `$('#text-area').text();`

Please help me return the array in `#text-ent` after 'button' click.

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Type Test</h1>
  <div id="div-text-area">
    <textarea id="text-area" ng-model="yourText" placeholder="Please enter your text here"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="text-result">{{yourText}}</div>
  <div id="entities1">
    <button>Get Entities</button>
    <div id="text-ent"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entities2">
    <button>Get Keywords</button>
    <div id="text-key"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function() {
    var getData = $('#text-area').text();
    var arrayOfText = getData.split(" ");
    $('#text-ent').text(arrayOfText[0]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Could not understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you rephrase your question a bit?

Comment: Use $('#text-area').val() not .text()

Comment: I have a text area to type in (#text-area), which ideally will contain several words separated by a space, on 'button' click I wanted to split() this string into an array which will be displayed in the #text-ent div.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get text-area value by .text() method which return inner HTML
so please try .val() which return the value of text-area

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('button').click(function() {
var getData = $('#text-area').val(); //Change here
var arrayOfText = getData.split(" ");
$('#text-ent').text(arrayOfText[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you mate, also D0D